# Why am I getting FROM keyword not found error?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT M.MFName AS "MANAGER FIRST NAME", 
       M.MLName, 
       M.MSalary, 
       M.MBDate 
       COUNT(*) AS "NUMBER OF BUILDINGS MANAGED"
  FROM MANAGER M, BUILDING B 
   WHERE M.MANAGERID = B.BMANAGERID AND M.MSALARY < 55000 
  GROUP BY MFNAME, MLNAME, MSALARY, MBDATE;
```

This query is giving me an error stating,  "ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected". Why am I getting this error?

Comment: You are missing a comma after `MBDate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax problem is that you are missing a commas after `MBDate` in the `FROM`.

Your query could really benefit from proper `join` syntax.  It should look like:

```
SELECT M.MFName AS "MANAGER FIRST NAME", M.MLName, M.MSalary, M.MBDate, COUNT(*) AS "NUMBER OF BUILDINGS MANAGED"
FROM MANAGER M JOIN
     BUILDING B 
     ON M.MANAGERID = B.BMANAGERID 
WHERE M.MSALARY < 55000 
GROUP BY m.MFNAME, m.MLNAME, m.MSALARY, m.MBDATE;
```

Comment: Here is what I did to get it to run correctly: SELECT M.MFName, M.MLName, M.MSalary, M.MBDate, COUNT(*) AS "Num Of Buildings Manager Manages"
FROM MANAGER M, BUILDING B 
WHERE M.MANAGERID = B.BMANAGERID AND M.MSALARY < 55000 
GROUP BY MFNAME, MLNAME, MSALARY, MBDATE;
 Thank you!